# desktop image is not loaded on browser

Tags: html

for displaying images on my website, I copied one image from my desktop that had already been downloaded from WhatsApp. But it is working when the image is address copied from the browser.
below is the code is given:
//`<img src="C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Webdesign challenge\bootstrap\Personal website for shilna\images\shi.png" class=" image-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Cinque Terre">`

Comment: The code is not visible in the question. Please edit the question, and add the code.

Comment: I see no code with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your image into your folder, then use relative paths.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp